# SQL Server Isolation Level issues

Tags: sql-server, isolation-level, transaction-isolation

I looked at all the isolation types.

But I could not find the mode I wanted.

*It can be read by other transaction during the transaction.
But, it will not add update and delete data.*

For example (pseudo code):

```
create table abc
(id uniqueidentifier primary key)

Create proc procMain
trans isolation level **??????**
insert abc (id) values (newid())
Waiting 10 minute
commit

Create proc procREAD
select * from abc

Create proc procAdd
insert abc (id) values (newid())

create proc procUpdate
update abc id = newid()

create proc procDelete
delete from abc


now;
exec procMain (abc table access read only and for other access: LOCKED)

(waiting...)

exec procRead (OK) (Readable)
exec procAdd (NO - never) (locked)
exec procUpdate (NO - never) (locked)
exec procDelete (NO - never) (locked)
```

Thanks...

Is there such an isolation level? (transaction isolation level?)

Comment: There is no isolation level which forbids you to update or delete data. It's not what are isolation levels supposed to do.

Comment: Actually I want to select serialize level. But the whole table is locked. Is there a row-based serialize isolation level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort of.  If you set the READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT database setting then READ COMMITTED sessions will not be blocked by in-flight transactions.  But they will see the "last-known-good" version of the rows, ie the state before the current transaction started.

David

Comment: I think, this is most sane variant.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `READ UNCOMMITTED`. [Learn more here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/snapshot-isolation-in-sql-server) Pay mind that this will lead to dirty reads.